# comparison of values in a column of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

CODE:-

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
from nsepy import get_history
import pandas as pd
import datetime



end1 = date.today()
start1 = end1 - timedelta(days=180)
stock = ['RELIANCE']#,'HDFCBANK','INFY','ICICIBANK','HDFC'] ,'TCS','KOTAKBANK','LT','SBIN','HINDUNILVR','AXISBANK',
         # 'ITC','BAJFINANCE','BHARTIARTL','ASIANPAINT','HCLTECH','MARUTI','TITAN','BAJAJFINSV','TATAMOTORS',
         # 'TECHM','SUNPHARMA','TATASTEEL','M&M','WIPRO','ULTRACEMCO','POWERGRID','HINDALCO','NTPC','NESTLEIND',
         # 'GRASIM','ONGC','JSWSTEEL','HDFCLIFE','INDUSINDBK','SBILIFE','DRREDDY','ADANIPORTS','DIVISLAB','CIPLA',
         # 'BAJAJ-AUTO','TATACONSUM','UPL','BRITANNIA','BPCL','EICHERMOT','HEROMOTOCO','COALINDIA','SHREECEM','IOC']



for stock in stock:
    vol = get_history(symbol=stock,
                  start=start1,
                  end=end1)


    d_vol = pd.concat([vol['Deliverable Volume']])
    symbol_s = pd.concat([vol['Symbol']])
    close = pd.concat([vol['Close']])

    df = pd.DataFrame(symbol_s)
    df['D_vol'] = d_vol
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns',10)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows',200)
    print(df)
```

PRODUCT:-

```
              Symbol     D_vol
Date                          
2022-02-17  RELIANCE   2872619
2022-02-18  RELIANCE   1216161
2022-02-21  RELIANCE   2888548
2022-02-22  RELIANCE   3920789
2022-02-23  RELIANCE   1928054
2022-02-24  RELIANCE   7266877
2022-02-25  RELIANCE   3670287
2022-02-28  RELIANCE   5321030
2022-03-02  RELIANCE   6277829
2022-03-03  RELIANCE   2479449
2022-03-04  RELIANCE   2754095
2022-03-07  RELIANCE   4962748
2022-03-08  RELIANCE   5602260
2022-03-09  RELIANCE   4647153
2022-03-10  RELIANCE   4102149
2022-03-11  RELIANCE   3028604
2022-03-14  RELIANCE   1800381
2022-03-15  RELIANCE   3924279
2022-03-16  RELIANCE   2824434
2022-03-17  RELIANCE   5961590
2022-03-21  RELIANCE   3019258
2022-03-22  RELIANCE   5753732
2022-03-23  RELIANCE   4321837
2022-03-24  RELIANCE   3208900
2022-03-25  RELIANCE   3821279
2022-03-28  RELIANCE   2149565
2022-03-29  RELIANCE   2280912
2022-03-30  RELIANCE   4259734
2022-03-31  RELIANCE   3893403
2022-04-01  RELIANCE   1845831
2022-04-04  RELIANCE   1859891
2022-04-05  RELIANCE   3962890
2022-04-06  RELIANCE   3640461
2022-04-07  RELIANCE   4936384
2022-04-08  RELIANCE   4458242
2022-04-11  RELIANCE   2103573
2022-04-12  RELIANCE   4019726
2022-04-13  RELIANCE   3009160
2022-04-18  RELIANCE   3079230
2022-04-19  RELIANCE   6735937
2022-04-20  RELIANCE   5767347
2022-04-21  RELIANCE   5151153
2022-04-22  RELIANCE   3113096
2022-04-25  RELIANCE   4210856
2022-04-26  RELIANCE   2382379
2022-04-27  RELIANCE   4014016
2022-04-28  RELIANCE   6937716
2022-04-29  RELIANCE   4308908
2022-05-02  RELIANCE   1939501
2022-05-04  RELIANCE   4758487
2022-05-05  RELIANCE   4135949
2022-05-06  RELIANCE   4117945
2022-05-09  RELIANCE   3496083
2022-05-10  RELIANCE   4214002
2022-05-11  RELIANCE   3471644
2022-05-12  RELIANCE   5344949
2022-05-13  RELIANCE   4652716
2022-05-16  RELIANCE   3089139
2022-05-17  RELIANCE   4085578
2022-05-18  RELIANCE   3948750
2022-05-19  RELIANCE   3713450
2022-05-20  RELIANCE   5198311
2022-05-23  RELIANCE   3078691
2022-05-24  RELIANCE   3094755
2022-05-25  RELIANCE   2740033
2022-05-26  RELIANCE   3568836
2022-05-27  RELIANCE   3519149
2022-05-30  RELIANCE   2716871
2022-05-31  RELIANCE  19734107
2022-06-01  RELIANCE   2072536
2022-06-02  RELIANCE   4788206
2022-06-03  RELIANCE   5136072
2022-06-06  RELIANCE   1680712
2022-06-07  RELIANCE   2712556
2022-06-08  RELIANCE   3012536
2022-06-09  RELIANCE   4301647
2022-06-10  RELIANCE   4608963
2022-06-13  RELIANCE   4242241
2022-06-14  RELIANCE   3299932
2022-06-15  RELIANCE   1888736
2022-06-16  RELIANCE   3664860
2022-06-17  RELIANCE   5410573
2022-06-20  RELIANCE   2410448
2022-06-21  RELIANCE   1906058
2022-06-22  RELIANCE   2129069
2022-06-23  RELIANCE   2980195
2022-06-24  RELIANCE   3440303
2022-06-27  RELIANCE   4127406
2022-06-28  RELIANCE   2590698
2022-06-29  RELIANCE   3617967
2022-06-30  RELIANCE   5419202
2022-07-01  RELIANCE  16124097
2022-07-04  RELIANCE   8925205
2022-07-05  RELIANCE   3241427
2022-07-06  RELIANCE   5356881
2022-07-07  RELIANCE   6400200
2022-07-08  RELIANCE   5266144
2022-07-11  RELIANCE   2790542
2022-07-12  RELIANCE   2091493
2022-07-13  RELIANCE   3820557
2022-07-14  RELIANCE   3162562
2022-07-15  RELIANCE   2013822
2022-07-18  RELIANCE   3641338
2022-07-19  RELIANCE   3280412
2022-07-20  RELIANCE   5571093
2022-07-21  RELIANCE   4032523
2022-07-22  RELIANCE   2374481
2022-07-25  RELIANCE   5024203
2022-07-26  RELIANCE   2368186
2022-07-27  RELIANCE   2097378
2022-07-28  RELIANCE   2973888
2022-07-29  RELIANCE   3783646
2022-08-01  RELIANCE   3695549
2022-08-02  RELIANCE   3420282
2022-08-03  RELIANCE   3725408
2022-08-04  RELIANCE   3215051
2022-08-05  RELIANCE   4106312
2022-08-08  RELIANCE   2615697
2022-08-10  RELIANCE   2941793
2022-08-11  RELIANCE   2296573
2022-08-12  RELIANCE   2683554
```

PROBLEM:-
See in above data frame there are around 180 rows. I have a list of 50 stocks but here I have displayed only one stock and its product and 49 comment out.
Now from the above data frame column `D_vol` contains around 180 rows. My criteria is that the last row of column `D_vol` should contain highest number than previous 90 rows or more than 90 rows. And if this condition satisfy any stock then it should reflect on output table.
ex:- if suppose RELIANCE contain 10000 as `D_vol` on 12-aug-2022 and before 12-aug it was contain less than 10000 for 90 days or more than 90 then that stock should reflect on my output table.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition like this:

```
result = list()
if df['D_vol'].iloc[-1] > max(df['D_vol'].iloc[-91:-1]):
    result.append(df)
```

Thus you get datasets where the last value is bigger than 90 previous ones.